how to animate draggableScrollableSheet and its contents in flutter?

I am trying to emulate this bottom sheet from the find my app on iOS.
I have used draggableScrollableSheet but it does not work as well as the one on find my.

class DraggableSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final String title;
  const DraggableSheet({super.key, required this.child, required this.title});

  @override
  State<DraggableSheet> createState() => _DraggableSheetState();
}

class _DraggableSheetState extends State<DraggableSheet> {
  final sheet = GlobalKey();
  final controller = DraggableScrollableController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.addListener(onChanged);
  }

  void onChanged() {
    final currentSize = controller.size;
    if (currentSize <= 0.10) collapse();
  }

  void collapse() => animateSheet(getSheet.snapSizes!.first);

  void anchor() => animateSheet(getSheet.snapSizes!.last);

  void expand() => animateSheet(getSheet.maxChildSize);

  void hide() => animateSheet(getSheet.minChildSize);

  void animateSheet(double size) {
    controller.animateTo(
      size,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      curve: Curves.easeIn,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    controller.dispose();
  }

  DraggableScrollableSheet get getSheet =>
      (sheet.currentWidget as DraggableScrollableSheet);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      return DraggableScrollableSheet(
        key: sheet,
        snapAnimationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        initialChildSize: 0.157,
        maxChildSize: 0.93,
        minChildSize: 0,
        expand: true,
        snap: true,
        snapSizes: const [
          0.157,
          0.4,
          0.93,
        ],
        controller: controller,
        builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
          return DecoratedBox(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: CupertinoTheme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
              boxShadow: const [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  blurRadius: 10,
                  spreadRadius: 1,
                  offset: Offset(0, 1),
                ),
              ],
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                topRight: Radius.circular(10),
              ),
            ),
            child: CustomScrollView(
              controller: scrollController,
              slivers: [
                BottomSheetHeader(title: widget.title),
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: widget.child,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    });
  }
}


It lacks the bounce snap animation and I could not figure out how they show the buttons like the Add items one on first snap (to ~half screen size) and then expand from the body (keeping the buttons at the bottom).
BottomSheetHeader
class BottomSheetHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  const BottomSheetHeader({super.key, required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverPersistentHeader(
      pinned: true,
      delegate: SliverAppBarDelegate(
        minHeight: 52,
        maxHeight: 52,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: CupertinoTheme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Wrap(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: 36,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4, bottom: 4),
                      height: 5,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.black26,
                        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                    child: Text(
                      title,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
              const Divider(
                height: 0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  SliverAppBarDelegate({
    required this.minHeight,
    required this.maxHeight,
    required this.child,
  });
  final double minHeight;
  final double maxHeight;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  double get minExtent => minHeight;
  @override
  double get maxExtent => max(maxHeight, minHeight);

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return SizedBox.expand(child: child);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return maxHeight != oldDelegate.maxHeight ||
        minHeight != oldDelegate.minHeight ||
        child != oldDelegate.child;
  }
}


Is there a better way to do this?

You could make a customize draggable sheet as of my knowledge with default controller that draggableScrollableSheet provides does not fully meet your requirements you need to handle it on your own, and then you can have more freedom to handle things your way.
